# Streamlit not waiting for function to finish

Tags: python, time, streamlit

I have a Streamlit script where I am using a function that fetches data, and it takes a while to run.
However, it seems like Streamlit is not waiting for the function to finish before restarting, leading to unexpected behavior.

Here is an example of my code, it is the the same but the output it's the same.

```
import time
import streamlit as st

number_list = []

max_iterations = 50

delay_seconds = 30

for i in range(max_iterations):
    number_list.append(i + 1)

    print(f"Appended {i + 1} to the list")

    time.sleep(delay_seconds)

st.write(number_list)
```

The output in my terminal is the following, and it can continue for ever

```
Appended 1 to the list
Appended 2 to the list
Appended 1 to the list
Appended 1 to the list
Appended 1 to the list
...
```

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: The code you provided seems to work fine. I have the output expected with i correctly incremented.